# Angular variable initialized using ng-init is always undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

I am learning AngularJS. Now I am initializing variable using ng-init. But the variable value is always undefined. My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angularjs popup</title>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/angular/angular-js.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="quantity=1;cost=5">

</section>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
    alert($scope.quantity)
})
</script>
</html>
```

When I run above code, it is always alerting "undefined" for quantity even if I initialized using ng-init. What is wrong with my code? Can I not initialize like that?

Comment: your `alert` in the controller is being executed before the `ng-init` has fired.

Comment: in general, you should *always* initialize variables in your controller;  `ng-init` is only [appropriate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!) in *very specific* cases.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone. Now I am clear with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-init in the template is being called after the initialisation of the app. If you were to put {{ quantity }} or {{ cost }} in your template you'd see your values displayed as expected.

May I ask, Why are you using ng-init? If you want to hard-code your values for quantity and cost you'd be better off doing it in your controller. It's worth looking at the angular docs for this, it suggests a similar approach

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit